# How do I add next and previous buttons to my slideshow with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I have a slideshow that automatically transitions to the next picture with a timer but I want to add more functionality by pausing and by also being able to go to the next or the previous image. I am confused though on how to add those event handlers?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var nextSlide = $("#slides img:first-child");
 var nextCaption;
 var nextSlideSource;
  
 // the function for running the slide show
    var runSlideShow = function() {   
        $("#caption").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#slide").fadeOut(1000,
         function () {
              if (nextSlide.next().length == 0) {
     nextSlide = $("#slides img:first-child");
    }
    else {
     nextSlide = nextSlide.next();
    }
    nextSlideSource = nextSlide.attr("src");
    nextCaption = nextSlide.attr("alt");
    $("#slide").attr("src", nextSlideSource).fadeIn(1000);     
    $("#caption").text(nextCaption).fadeIn(1000);
   }
  )
 }
 
 // start the slide show
 var timer = setInterval(runSlideShow, 3000);
 
})
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 380px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
h1, h2, ul, p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
h1 {
 padding-bottom: .25em;
 color: blue;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 120%;
 padding: .5em 0;
}
img {
 height: 250px;
}
#slides img {
 display: none;
}
#buttons {
 margin-top: .5em;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Xochitl Menjivar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="slide_show.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<main>
    <h1>Fishing Slide Show</h1>
    <h2 id="caption">Casting on the Upper Kings</h2>
    <img id="slide" src="images/casting1.jpg" alt="">
    <div id="slides"> 
        <img src="images/casting1.jpg" alt="Casting on the Upper Kings">
        <img src="images/casting2.jpg" alt="Casting on the Lower Kings">
        <img src="images/catchrelease.jpg" alt="Catch and Release on the Big Horn">
        <img src="images/fish.jpg" alt="Catching on the South Fork">
        <img src="images/lures.jpg" alt="The Lures for Catching">
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
     <input type="button" id="prev" value="Previous" disabled>
     <input type="button" id="play" value="Pause">
     <input type="button" id="next" value="Next" disabled>      
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhwhLd01/)

For play/pause you can do this

```
$('#play').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    isPaused = !isPaused;

    if(isPaused){
        $('#play').val('Play');
        window.clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
        $('#play').val('Pause');
        timer = setInterval(runSlideShow, 3000)
    }
})
```

Declare variable for tracking play/pause state. When it is in pause state, clear `timer` interval, if state is play, then set interval `timer` again.

Also, you could have added this flag inside `runSlideShow()` function

```
var runSlideShow = function() {
    if(!isPaused){
        $("#caption").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#slide").fadeOut(1000,
            function () {
                findNextSlide()
                nextSlideSource = nextSlide.attr("src");
                nextCaption = nextSlide.attr("alt");
                $("#slide").attr("src", nextSlideSource).fadeIn(1000);                  
                $("#caption").text(nextCaption).fadeIn(1000);
            }
        )
    }
}
```

And click event would be quite short.

```
$('#play').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    isPaused = !isPaused;
})
```

For next slide one option, would be just simply clear and start `runSlideShow`, which will automatically force to fetch new slide with all effects.

Show previous slide, you can use same logic, and instead finding next slide, just look for previous slide. jQuery has function `.prev()` which is opposite of `.next()`

**Edit:**

```
function findPreviousSlide(){
    if (nextSlide.prev().length == 0) {
        nextSlide = $("#slides img:last-child");
    }
    else {
        nextSlide = nextSlide.prev();
    }
}
```

Comment: So for the previous button should I do something like $("#slide").prev(); to retrieve the previous slide? I'm still new to jQuery so I'm still not sure how to use all of these methods.

Comment: That's right. Try to find couple minutes a day to visit jQuery API and look at the examples ;)